# Specification for image ads in mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ads

What are some specifications for fetching and showing image ads, especially interstitial ads and native ads, in mobile apps?

Like VAST is for video ads, what is there for image ads?

Comment: Interstitial ads are full-screen ads that cover the interface of their host app. They're typically displayed at natural transition points in the flow of an app, such as between activities or during the pause between levels in a game

Comment: @HussainAbbas I was not asking the definition of interstitial ads.